# Jquery (this) help

Tags: jquery, this, jquery-hover

Just wanted some quick help I'm 90% sure i need to use the (this) call/function because i need it to work on multiple objects on the page. but im not sure where or how to place it into my jquery code, im trying to create a hover state for a object once the user rolls over another , here is my jquery code, I hope this makes sense, thanks!

```
    $("li.projectpost").hover(function () {
    $("div.portfolio-title a").toggleClass("highlighter");
    });
```

Basically all i really want to know is, I have more than one element on the page that I would like to apply a hover effect to, as is right now, when i hover over one item they all change, but I want to know is how to change the css in a child element when rolled over a parent I guess,  I have a Div wrapper, that when hovered  over an inside div changes, does that make better sense, Still trying to wrap my head around jquery thanks for the help! :)

Thanks for the help everyone! I just figured this out, I needed to use -
    jQuery(this).find(); thanks!

Comment: I am not being snide here, your question genuinely does not make sense. `this` is a scope operator and in javascript can mean a whole lot of things depending on context. Is your function not working and you are just speculating that using `this` would help resolve the issue?

Comment: A HTML snippet would be helpful so we could see the relationship between `li.projectpost` and `div.portfolio-title a`

Comment: Basically all i really want to know is, I have more than one element on the page that I would like to apply a hover effect to, as is right now, when i hover over one item they all change, but I want to know is how to change the css in a child element when rolled over a parent I guess, I have a Div wrapper, that when hovered over an inside div changes, does that make better sense, Still trying to wrap my head around jquery thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I just figured this out, I needed to use - jQuery(this).find(); thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone! I just figured this out, I needed to use -

```
jQuery(this).find(" ");
```

Inorder to select elements inside each other so my code ended up looking like this

```
    $("li.projectpost").hover(function () {
    // This will call when mouse is over
    jQuery(this).find(".portfolio-title a").css("color","#00fcff");
    }, function(){
    // This will call when mouse is out
    jQuery(this).find(".portfolio-title a").css("color","#ececec");
    });
```

So far it seems to work great! thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass two callback functions to hover if you need that. I don't clearly get what you're doing there but I think this is what you need:

```
$("li.projectpost").hover(function () {
    // This will call when mouse is over
    }, function(){
    // This will call when mouse is out
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/tbq3x/13/

Just try the above fiddle. Your code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li.projectpost").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighter");
});
```

The above should work, tell me how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in `$(document).ready()` method

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("li.projectpost").hover(function () {
    $("div.portfolio-title a").toggleClass("highlighter");
    });

});
```

Comment: I do have that in place , i just took my code in between ;) thanks though!